# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp. ||| Runing a google script to generate contracts

Tags: object, documentation

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Contracte');
  menu.addItem('Generare automata', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  //This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('d/18vHG-P0gPtpbSdV-6TrjnZoVnNEmcP5jt5dm8xxe2ZI');
  
    //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1lI5m-lRDuQYanddP0pdDEIY0fMkgNeWG')
  //Here we store the sheet as a variable
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName('Data')
  
  //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //Start processing each spreadsheet row
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    //Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
    if (index === 0) return;
    //Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
    if (row[17]) return;
    //Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Contract nr. ${row[0]}, ${row[4]}` , destinationFolder)
    //Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
    //All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
    const body = doc.getBody();
    //In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
    //const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();
    
    //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
    body.replaceText('{{Nr. Doc. prov1}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Nr. Doc. prov2}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Data prov1}}', row[2]);
    //body.replaceText('{{Data prov1}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Data prov2}}', row[3]);
    //body.replaceText('{{Data prov2}}', friendlyDate);
    body.replaceText('{{Nume Client}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Nr. Reg.Com.}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{CUI}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{Adresa Sediu}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{Adresa Facturare}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{Reprezentant Legal}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{Functie}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{Apeluri Simultane}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{Cantitate Numere Alocate}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{Lista de Numere Alocate}}', row[13]);
    body.replaceText('{{Tel Contact}}', row[14]);
    body.replaceText('{{E-mail}}', row[15]);
    
    //We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
    doc.saveAndClose();
    //Store the url of our new document in a variable
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    //Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url)
    
  })
  
}
```

When running my script, I encountered the following error:

Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp.

I have checked and ensured that all the necessary permissions and access rights are properly set. I have enabled the Drive API service in my Google Cloud Platform project, and the script should have the required access to the Drive service.

I have tried running the script multiple times, but the error persists. I have also verified that there are no temporary connectivity issues or service disruptions from Google's end.